# Sharepoint List change notification incorrect

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, custom-list

I have setup an alert on a Sharepoint list for when new items are created or any changes etc.

I have noticed that when someone changes *any* field on the form, all of the text area fields show a change, even though the value didn't actually change.

So there is a greyed-out line that's struck out, then directly below it is the exact same content, implying that the user changed the value.

The form was designed with InfoPath, and I don't recall having the issue before that. See below example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a normal behavior, the Alert is working on **List Item** level **NOT** on a particular field.

If a specific field is changed in the list item that means the list item has been changed and the alert will fire to show list item (all fields).

**In the Alert settings**, you can

- Send an alert for every change.
- Send an alert when a new item is added to the list or library.
- Send an alert when an existing item is modified.
- Send an alert when items are deleted.

> **So** you **cannot** configure alert for a specific column/field as OOTB, instead try to use Workflow.

Comment: I understand that, what I am saying is that there are fields on the form that haven't changed at all, that are struck out and replaced with the same text again, implying that they have been changed by the user. Not all fields do this, only some. I've just added a screenshot to hopefully explain a bit better.